# how to pass the redux action to axios response interceptor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, axios

I am doing the access token refresh in react and axios response interceptor, when the server return access token invalid or expired. the client will send a refresh token reqeust and resend the queue request which was stored when token refreshing period. Now I am facing a problem that after resend the queue request, I need to dispatch the data and trigger the UI rerender, I could not get the action name in the response interceptor. So I did not known where to dispath, this is the dispatch code look like:

```
// refresh the access token
      ResponseHandler.handleWebCommonFailure(response.data)
        .then((data: any) => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          pendingRequestsQueue.forEach((request) => {
            const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(WheelGlobal.ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME);
            request.headers['x-access-token'] = accessToken;
            request.headers['x-request-id'] = uuid();
            instance(request).then((resp:any) => {
              // get the action of original request?????
              const action = request.action;
              const data = resp.data.result;
              // change the state to make it render the UI
              store.dispatch(action(data));
            });
          });
          pendingRequestsQueue = [];
        });
```

I tried to get the action from request but failed, this is how I get the request:

```
  const originalRequest: InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any> = response.config;
```

what should I do to pass the action to the axios response interceptor? is it possible to pass action into axios response interceptor? what I think is that I could put the aciton name to http header, and get the header from response. any suggestion? I have tried like this, when send http,put the action into header:

```
export function requestWithAction(config: any, action: any) {
  const actionJson = action.toString();
  config.headers['x-action'] = btoa(actionJson);
  return instance(config).then(
    (response: { data: { result: any; }; }) => {
      const data = response.data.result;
      store.dispatch(action(data));
      return response.data;
    }
  ).catch(
    (error: any) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}
```

get the header from response interceptor and dispatch like this:

```
instance(request).then((resp:any) => {
              const functionStr = atob(response.config.headers['x-action']);
              const action = eval(`(${functionStr})`);
              const data = resp.data.result;
              // change the state to make it render the UI
              store.dispatch(action(data));
            });
```

evert thing works but it seems the dispatch not trigger the action.